# How to fix "Module not found: app.server.module.ngfactory" when building server in Angular Universal?

Tags: angular, universal

I am following https://angular.io/guide/universal to add Angular Universal to my project. At step 3, when I do `ng run [project]:server` I get the following error at around 92%:

`ERROR in ./src/main.server.ts 
 Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './../app/app.server.module.ngfactory 
 in '\[angular-project-folder]\apps\[project]\src`

`ng run [project]:build` works as expected.

My angular version is 6.01 btw.

Anybody know why this is happening and how I can resolve it? Thank you.

Answer (score 6):

Got this working now. The `tsconfig.server.ts` was one folder up in my project, therefore inside my tsconfig file:

```
"angularCompilerOptions": {
    "entryModule": "app/app.server.module#AppServerModule"
}
```

had to be

```
"angularCompilerOptions": {
    "entryModule": "src/app/app.server.module#AppServerModule"
}
```

Comment: Great, except it's in tsconfig.server.json, not tsconfig.server.js